# open source docker Image vulnerability and security scanner for images hosted on a private docker registry

Tags: docker, jenkins, nexus, docker-registry, docker-image

We have a private docker registry (Sonatype nexus) which holds all our private docker images. I was looking for an open source vulnerability and security scanner for scanning all the images on the private registry also I want to install the tool on the linux box and also integrate with Jenkins.

I came across Twistlock, Anchore, Dagda. None of these seems to provide a tool which can be installed and used without any license.

Any inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Clair:

https://github.com/coreos/clair

Simply follow the instruction:

https://github.com/arminc/clair-scanner#run

replace the date on the clair-db image with either latest or a specific date from

https://hub.docker.com/r/arminc/clair-db/tags/

you can get the scanner binaries here:

https://github.com/arminc/clair-scanner/releases

Answer (score 0):

I too would say to use CoreOS Clair for this purpose. However a few things to consider,

1. How you gonna run Clair i.e. As Docker compose or in your kube cluster?
2. Clair provides Static Scanning only (only the container image, not the running container)
3. What sort of integration tools you are using?

If you thinking to integrate with your CI/CD pipelines, the best Clair client I can recommend is Klar because it is much simple and straightforward to use. clairctl can also be used but it gives some hard time when troubleshooting with permission errors.